# Ateshgah of Baku, Azerbaijan - A Shakthi Peetha in Central Asia?

Tags: temple, shakti

It has been established that Ateshgah temple in Baku, Azerbaijan is indeed a Hindu temple and not a Zoroastrian temple with discovery of Sanskrit inscriptions praising Lord Shiva and Lord Ganesha as shown in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ateshgah_of_Baku#History) wiki article. My questions are as follows.

1. Is there any proof to the popular perception that it is one of the 54 Shakti Peeth? The association is made with Shakti Peeth because the Baku temple resembles the Jwalamukhi Shakti Peeth in Himachal Pradesh where one can find the 'eternal flames' as well.
2. Is there any records of pilgrimage to the Baku temple either during the medieval ages or later, in any western or Indian historical archives?
3. What is the estimated data of construction of the temple? It must have been a time when Paganism/Hinduism had considerable influence in Central Asia which must push the date well before 1000 AD.

Comment: The Wikipedia article you linked to says the temple was built in the 17th or 18th century.  And this Wikipedia article says that Hindus were in Azerbaijan until the late 1800's: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism_in_Azerbaijan